# Seeking a method for finding feasible directions

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the domain $D$ of real numbers $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(x)\leq y\leq g(x)$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are twice differentiable convex functions over $x\in [0,1]$ such that $0\leq f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $f(0)=g(0)=0$.

Now, the cone of feasible directions of $D$ at a point $x_0\in D\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined as the set of numbers $d\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $x_0+\lambda d\in D$ for all $\lambda\in (0,\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$.

**I am theoretically interested in finding a method for finding the feasible direction at $(0,0)$ for the set $D$ given above.**

I have tried the following. Let $h_1(x,y)=f(x)-y$ and $h_2(x,y)=y-g(x)$. Note that $h_i(0,0)=0$ for $i=1,2$, and that for all $(x,y)\in D$ we have $h_1(x,y)\leq 0$ and $h_2(x,y)\leq 0$. This means that if $d$ is to be a feasible direction at $(0,0)$ (i.e., an element of the cone of feasible directions at $(0,0)$), then the value of $h_i$, $i=1,2$, must stay the same at $0$, or must decrease.

I have proven a theorem (in an exercise in a book on convex optimization) that says the following: For a convex function $u:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable at $(x,y)$, the existence of a vector $d\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\nabla u(x,y)^t d\leq 0$ is equivalent to the existence of a vector $d\in\mathbb{R}^2$ and a real number $\delta>0$ such that $u((x,y)+\lambda d)\leq u(x,y)$ for all $\lambda\in (0,\delta)$ (note: such a vector $d$ may be called a *non-strict descent direction*).

Thus, to find a method, I would first note that $h_1(x,y)=f(x)+(-y)$ is a sum of convex functions, and thus convex, and then apply the above result, to say that a feasible direction of $D$ at $(0,0)$ must be such that $\nabla h_1(0,0)^t d\leq 0$ or $$(f'(x),-1)\begin{pmatrix}d_1\\ d_2\end{pmatrix} \leq 0.$$ This ensures us that as we move along the direction $d$ in such a way that we do not increase the value of $h_1$ from $(0,0)$ at which it attains its highest value $0$.

However, the function $h_2(x,y)=y-g(x)$ is not necessarily convex, as $-g(x)$ is concave since $g(x)$ is convex. Though I would *want* to say something like " $(-g'(x),1)\begin{pmatrix}d_1\\ d_2\end{pmatrix} \leq 0$ must hold for all feasible non-strict directions of descent $d$ of $D$ at $(0,0)$", my theorem does not guarantee this.

So is there some general method or way of thinking to find feasible directions of $D$ at $(0,0)$?

**To take a concrete example, let $f(x)=(e-1)x^2$ and $g(x)=e^x-1$. Both are convex, and they are shown below. The question, then, arises: What are the feasible directions of the set $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|0\leq x\leq 1,\quad f(x)\leq y\leq g(x)\}$ at $(0,0)$?**

The method by which we answer the above problem will, I hope, shed some light on how to find a feasible direction in general.

[image: What are the feasible directions at $(0,0)$?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that $f$ and $g$ are twice differentiable. Then the set consists of all conic combinations of $[1,f'(0)]$ and $[1,g'(0)]$. The set may not be closed (in your example, $[1,0]$ is not a feasible direction), so you may need to exclude the extreme rays. The ray for $f$ should be excluded if $f$ is strictly convex on $(0,\delta)$, while the ray for $g$ should be excluded if $g$ is strictly concave on $(0,\delta)$ (for some $\delta>0$).

Let me provide the proof for the ray for $f$. Take $\delta$ small enough such that $f$ strictly convex on $(0,\delta)$ and let $x \in (0,\delta)$. By Taylor's theorem and the mean value theorem, $f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)(x-0) + f''(a)(x-0)^2$ for some $a \in (0,\delta)$. This simplifies to $f(x) = f'(0)x + f''(a)x^2$. The second term is positive since $f$ is strictly convex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how do you derive that the set consists of all conic combinations of $(1,f'(0))$ and $(1,g'(0))$? In my example, $(1,f'(0))=(1,0)$ and $(1,g'(0))=(1,1)$ so the set of all conic combinations is $(\alpha+\beta,\beta)$, for real numbers $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$. Interestingly, with my approach presented in the question I get the same conclusion: I need $d$ to satisfy $-d_1+d_2\leq 0$ and $d_2\geq 0$, i.e. $0\leq d_2\leq d_1$, which gives all conic combinations between $(1,1)$ and $(1,0)$. Is my method essentially the same?

Comment: They are essentially the same indeed. Where you say "I have proven a theorem", you could have used Taylor's theorem and the mean value theorem.